# Using Python, write an Excel file with columns copied from another Excel file

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt, xlsxwriter

I have an Excel file containing a varying number of columns, I would like to loop through certain columns (from their header row value) of that file using Python, then write (copy) those columns to another Excel file.

Any examples on how I can do this please?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Here are some options to choose from:

- [xlwt](http://www.python-excel.org/) (writing xls files)
- [xlrd](http://www.python-excel.org/) (reading xls/xlsx files)
- [openpyxl](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/) (reading/writing xlsx files)
- [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) (writing xlsx files)

If you need to copy only data (without formatting information), you can just use any combination of these tools for reading/writing. If you have an `xls` file, you should go with xlrd+xlwt option.

Here's a simple example of copying the first row from the existing excel file to the new one:

```
import xlwt
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('input.xls')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

data = [sheet.cell_value(0, col) for col in range(sheet.ncols)]

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet('test')

for index, value in enumerate(data):
    sheet.write(0, index, value)

workbook.save('output.xls')
```

Comment: Hi, could you please tell me how to copy a column instead of a row?

Comment: @MikeIssa sure, I think you just need to swap `index` and 0 (0 would be the column index you want to copy).

Comment: Figured it out. `data = [sheet.cell_value(row, 0) for row in range(sheet.nrows)]`

Comment: In 2020, the best/easiest option may be pandas dataframe.read_excel and pandas dataframe.to_excel. ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html -- pandas appears to use xlsxwriter under the hood, so that is probably the best maintained standalone package of the 4 now.

Comment: how to read the value of cell row=1,col=1 with xlwt package ?