# python script for getting some columns of one excel into new one

Tags: python, excel

[image]
I am new to Python. I have to create another Excel file from my test report Excel file.

I need to create a new excel file as 'test result summery' with columns-values like `test case ID` and 'Function loop1', 'function loop2' which is result of resp test case etc from my test_report.xls (as in below image) Can anybody share some Python script for this?

Comment: Can you post what you have, so we could help you more.

Comment: Just throw the image URL in the comments,so that I can understand what the problem is, and try to help you. Instead of just telling you to use this library or that.

Comment: i tried to attach an image but it failed ok , in short i have my excel file for test cases as follows
TCID    Description    Expected      Actual          Loop 1 loop2
TC_0001 make switch on light shall on light gets on  Pass   pass
TC_002  make switch off light shall off light is on  FAIL   FAIL

from this source excel file i only have to create another excel with columns TC_ID and Result like Loop 1 , Loop 2 with its data , please share some code for windows xp

Comment: What do you mean by "Windows Xp"? Are you not using Python?

Comment: yes using same but just for more info

Comment: how can add image for ur ref , it states needs some 10 reputation etc while attaching image

Comment: do you have enough reputation now?

Comment: You now have 10 reputation. You should be able to add your picture now

Comment: @Sara Can you post a picture now?

Comment: hi andy , i gote reputation hence added image , can you help me out with a script as per my description ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use csv lib for this.

 More information here:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

You would start with something like:

```
import csv
outputfile = open('Your Desired File Name', 'wb')
DataWriter = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
DataWriter.writerow(['Test Case ID', 'Result'])
DataWriter.writerow(#Some data that you want to add)
outputfile.close() # Close the file
```

Comment: TC_ID    TS_STEP    ACTUAL     RESULT_LOOP1    RESULT_LOOP2
TC001    BAT ON     LIGHT ON   PASS            PASS   
TC002    BAT OFF    LIGHT oFF  PASS            FAIL

only want a seperate excel with TC_ID and LOOP1, LOOP2 etc

Comment: @Sara Sorry I don't understand what you really want.

Comment: yes , sorry , i thought it will appear like rows and column view easy to understand but its displaying in a line

Answer (score 0):

Use python libraries `xlrd` and `xlwt`.

```
import xlrd, xlwt

workbook1 = xlrd.open_workbook('my_workbook.xls')
worksheet1 = workbook1.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
row = 0
col = 0
cell_value = worksheet1.cell_value(row, col)

workbook2 = xlwt.Workbook()
workssheet2 = workbook2.add_sheet('A Test Sheet')
workssheet2.write(row, col, cell_value)
workbook2.save('output.xls')
```

Another example: [Using Python, write an Excel file with columns copied from another Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560289/python-write-an-excel-file-with-columns-from-another-excel-file)

Comment: hi prashant do u have some examples

Comment: I have added some simple examples and you will find many more on Google.