# Create/write to an excel file in python- Import Error

Tags: python-3.x, importerror

I am working on Python 3.2.5 version and my requirement is to create and write to an excel file. I tried with `xlsxwriter` and `xlwt` both, but ended up in getting `ImportError`. I can't install these modules.

Any other module which does excel creation please?

Answer (score 1):

I think your `python excel lib` are not yet contained in `python library path`.

Window:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\XlsxWriter
```

In other platform, also you should try to put `XlsxWriter` library under site-packages. It can solve the `ImportError`.

Comment: Sorry to say this, I can't use these modules anyway because of some other issues. If any other module is available, then would be really helpful for my scenario. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: This module also python excel read/write available >>> https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd.

Comment: Can 'xlrd' help to create/write an excel file?

Comment: This source will be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560289/using-python-write-an-excel-file-with-columns-copied-from-another-excel-file